# How to point my subdomain to a particular port with nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, portforwarding

I am trying to point my subdomain to a particular port of my server, but the issue is that when I go to that subdomain it shows:
**This site can’t be reached**

What I need is like this:
When i go to `https://auth.domain.com`, to point me to my server on aws: `https://ec2.domain.aws:8443`, but its failing to do so

Here's my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /angularapp/dist;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  auth.domain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://ec2.domain.aws:8443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

What I was trying to do here is that in the first server when it access to localhost (domain.com) to just show the index.html file **which is working perfectly**, and on my second server when the user tries to access to `auth.domain.com` to point that to `https://ec2.domain.aws:8443`.

Am I missing something or this is just not the way that I should do it?

Also the second server solution I found it on:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-point-my-custom-domain-to-my-ip-port-41-111-20-36-8080

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

please try using the config as below.

```
location auth.domain.com {
               proxy_pass https://ec2.domain.aws:8443;
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
```

Comment: should I also let the `server_name auth.domain.com` and `listen 80` in the second server?

Answer (score 0):

Set HTTP `Host` header equal to your AWS domain name:

```
proxy_set_header Host ec2.domain.aws;
```

If this does not help, try turning on SNI for proxied HTTPS requests with the [`proxy_ssl_server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name) directive:

```
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```